# Geometric Intuition behind trace and matrix non-commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, trace

My intuition of trace is that it is essentially asking, for each basis, where does this basis vector go, and what is the new vector's component in its original basis. Then, trace is a sum of those terms.

And matrix non-commutativity makes sense. You apply one transformation, then the next. And this can lead to differences in the result of $AB$ and $BA$.

But if matrices multiplication is non-commutative, then why, in light of my intuition of trace, is trace cyclic. $$\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)$$

I can show it numerically, but I'd like to be able to think of it in a more intuitive and geometric way.

Comment: It's a good question, but I want to point out that your intuition of trace isn't really geometric—it requires a basis, and it's not obvious that it is independent of that basis.

Comment: The question, as written, could be rephrased as:  what is the intuition behind the fact that traces of commutators (of finite dimensional transformations) are zero?  (Since $tr(AB-BA)=0$ means the same thing.)

Comment: I enjoyed the comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275334/19965) roughly "Trace is the last thing that believes two matrices commute."

Comment: Another message I seemed to be getting is that the trace is the second-order information about deformation of the volume of the parallelpiped. So in that case, it would seem that one should say the second-order deformation is the same if you apply the transformations in either order.

Comment: The link https://mathoverflow.net/q/13526/41139 posted by Rschwieb is certainly worth checking out: it is basically your question with almost 30 answers